# Insert multiple rows SQL from a form with same titles

Tags: php, sql, sql-insert

I have this form, which when you click on "New row" there are popping up another field with new inputs. What I want to achieve with this is an user-friendly form which FOREACH "New item" ->

```
("INSERT 
INTO menues(
    restaurant_id,
    title, 
    subtitle, 
    name, 
    ingredients, 
    price, 
    category, 
    upload_date
    )
VALUES(
    :restaurant_id,
    :title, 
    :subtitle, 
    :name, 
    :ingredients, 
    :price, 
    :category,
    NOW()
    )
");
```

When adding multiply rows, every row shall have the same values from the upper field of the form(title, subtitle) + restaurant_id and category **BUT** different values for name, ingredients and price.

In what way can I achieve this?

***The form:***

[image: Before clicking]
When clicked "New row" >>
[image: After Clicking]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your input fields return an array:

```
<input type="text" name="food_name[]" />
<input type="text" name="food_ingredient[]" />
<input type="text" name="food_price[]" />
```

and then loop through the results:

```
$name = $_POST["food_name"];
$ingredient = $_POST["food_ingredient"];
$price = $_POST["food_price"];
$length = count($name);
for($key=0;$key<$length;$key++){
 echo $name[$key] . "<br/>"; 
 echo $ingredient[$key] . "<br/>"; 
 echo $price[$key] . "<br/>";  
 echo "-----<br/>";
}
```

That's how I did it, when I had your problem.

Comment: Yep I did the same. Use an array for your input fields, and loop through results. Works perfectly!

Comment: @NabilGhulam What's not working? Do you have some error codes? It could be your dynamic inserted input-fields, which isn't setup correctly.

Comment: I just don't know how to do it. How do you get the query to count how many values there should be? I reposted this question, maybe you could try to solve it there? :) [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794854/automate-values-based-on-how-many-inputs-the-form-contains) - Might be clearer of what I want

Answer (score 0):

This is a php question I would think.  Read values from your form into an array.  Then run another code block to insert the array into your table using the for each construct and insert the elements of the array using your sql statement into your table iteratively until the array is exhausted.